# Cached uid on autofs filesystems

Tags: mount, cache, opensolaris, autofs

We have some issues with homedirs on our NFS server (SUN S7110). When we change the owner of a file it seems the old uid is cached. The ls -l  still shows the old uid. On other systems which mount the same homedir the  has the new uid. Is there a caching mechanism or something like that?

We use opensolaris B134 and autofs to mount the homedirs.

Thanks,
Martijn

Answer (score 1):

Yes, attributes such as uid are cached by the NFS client.   On Solaris & OpenSolaris the options to control how long they're cached are documented in [the `mount_nfs(1m)` man page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19253-01/816-5166/6mbb1kqa7/index.html) - see the option names starting with `ac` like `actimeo` and the later man page sections they reference, such as *File Attributes* and *Specifying Values for Attribute Cache  Duration Options*.